# Bash: passing around compound commands

Tags: bash

I have a Bash function named "inDir" which abstracts the "go to a directory, do something, and come back to the starting directory" pattern.  It is defined as:

```
inDir() {
    if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
        local dir="$1"
        local cwd=`pwd`
        shift

        if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
            cd "$dir" && "$@"
            cd "$cwd"
        fi
    fi
}
```

I am trying to create a function whose semantics don't matter much, but will essentially run:

```
inDir /tmp { [ -e testFile ] && touch testFile }
```

I hope the "implied" semantics are clear.  I want to go into a directory, check if $somefile exists, and if it does, delete it.  This is not working as intended.  If I run:

```
cd
inDir /tmp [ -e testFile ] && touch testFile
```

it checks if testFile exists in /tmp, and then tries to touch it in ~.  Can anybody think of a good way to invoke inDir so that it accepts "compound" commands?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `pushd` and `popd`?

Comment: @sarnold: Throw it in a subshell and you don't even need to popd

Comment: @Seth, hah, nice and lazy. :)

Comment: I've been avoiding subshells because I want to be able to see the results of processing.  For example, some uses of inDir call wget.  pushd and popd are definite possibilities.

Comment: subshells don't hide anything, and when you are talking about (list), it is actually a "subshell environment" and doesn't actually fork anything.  It just will implicitly discard variable assignments, directory changes, and other shell state changes when you leave the parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
indir() {
 if [ -d "$1" ]; then
  local dir="$1"
  shift
  (cd "$dir" && eval "$@")
 fi
}

indir /tmp touch testFile
indir /tmp "[ -e testFile ] && rm testFile"
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Just tell it to invoke a subshell.

```
inDir /tmp bash -c "[ -e testFile ] && touch testFile"
```